# React native branch.io share content issue

Tags: react-native, share, branch.io

i want to share my short url content as below format

```
My Share title

please check below link:

https://link.app.my.app/6pZknA8YNU

-via MyApp
```

Below is my code

```
let customlink = ((item.url ? item.url : item.url))
  let branchUniversalObject = await branch.createBranchUniversalObject('canonicalIdentifier', {
    locallyIndex: true,
    title: 'News Sharing',
    contentDescription: item.title,
    contentImageUrl: item.media[0].url,

  })

  let shareOptions = { messageHeader: '', messageBody: item.title + "\n" + "please check below link:"  + "\n" + '-via MyApp'  }
  let linkProperties = { feature: 'share', channel: 'MyApp' }
  let controlParams = { $desktop_url: customlink, $ios_url: customlink, $android_url: customlink } 
  let { channel, completed, error } = await branchUniversalObject.showShareSheet(shareOptions, linkProperties, controlParams)
```

When i run above code i am getting below message format

```
My Share title

please check below link:

-via MyApp

https://link.app.my.app/6pZknA8YNU
```

Any idea how can i get as per my expected format ?